# Specifying sequence of colors in ListPlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to figure out how to use Mathematica's color schemes with discrete data. For example, I have a list of time series in the form

```
s={{{1946,1},{1947,2},{1948,3}},{{1946,-2},{1947,-1.8}}}
```

and so on; there are about 30 series of varying length. If I plot/join/overlay these series using `ListPlot`, is there a way to instruct Mathematica to select colors for each plot by taking evenly spaced colors from a `ColorFunction` returned by `ColorData` (e.g., `"Rainbow"`)?

How would I combine this with a directive to make each plot `Thick`?

```
ListPlot[s,Joined->True,PlotStyle->{Thick,???}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagine this is your data - a ragged list of 30 lists of varied length:

```
data = Table[.5 k + RandomReal[1, RandomInteger[{8, 14}]], {k, 30}];
```

Is it what you need?

```
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
         PlotStyle -> Thread@{Thick, ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Range[0, 1, 1/29]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm confused; shouldn't `Flatten` be `Thread`?  Why does the form produced by `Flatten` work?  I would expect that would style the first line `Thick` and then the rest in color.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are right, `Thread` is cleaner, updated. I just know from experience that`Flatten` works.

Comment: Okay.  I'd still like to know why `{thick, color, color, . . .}` works, if you have an explanation.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this is how this syntax is setup up to parse into Graphics - take a look at the InputForm